# C++, Object with a list of objects: no match for 'operator=='

Tags: c++, list, if-statement, iterator

I have a class called 'order', and another one called 'orderbook'.

The orderbook contains a list of orders. What I would like to do is find whether a certain value of order (order.security) already exists in the orderbook.

To do that, I created an iterator which is supposed to cycle through the list to find whether that value exists. However I must be doing something wrong somewhere, as I get the following g++ error:

error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator*() == __val'|

Note: the functions arent complete yet

```
void matchOrder(order &orderEntry, orderbook &genericBook);


void fillBook(order &orderEntry, orderbook &bookBUY, orderbook &bookSELL)
{
    if (orderEntry.side == "S")
        {
            //Check if any buy can be fulfilled
            matchOrder(orderEntry, bookSELL);
        }
}

void matchOrder(order &orderEntry, orderbook &genericBook)
{
    //scan book, if find a matching SECURITY, check order type and quantity (and price)

    list<order>::iterator pos;

    pos = find (genericBook.myList.begin(), genericBook.myList.end(), orderEntry);

    if (pos !=  genericBook.myList.end())
        cout << "\n\n   FOUND ONE!!!!!";
}
```

for reference, the following is my order class:

```
class order{

public:
    void getOrderData(int j, DATA fullData);

    string security;
    string type;
    int quantity;
    double price;
    string name;
    string side;
};
```

and my orderbook class:

```
class orderbook
{

public:

    list<order> myList;
    list<order>::iterator it;
    void printItOut();

};
```

Comment: Does `order` overload `operator==`?

Comment: No, neither does `orderbook`. I will add my `order` class on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pos = find (genericBook.myList.begin(), genericBook.myList.end(), orderEntry);
```

in order for `find` to work on `genericBook.myList` it needs some way of checking if two `order`s are equal. It does this by using the `operator ==`. Your `order` class should provide this operator for find to work properly.

You can solve it by overloading the `== operator` for `order` class.

Comment: Alright I see what you mean. Would overloading the `==` operator in the `order` class still allow me to use the regular `==` operator for the members of order class?

Comment: @msmf14, Yes, you define the two parameter types and that's why it's overloading.

Comment: @msmf14 Yes of course. `order1.security == order1.security` will still be `string` comparison and should work normal. same for other members. The overloading helps to resolve cases like `order1 == order2`. i.e. class wide comparison.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much @chris and stardust_, I'll get working on it!

Comment: @chris. I feel like I stole this from you. :) but on my defence I saw your comment after posting the answer :)

Comment: @stardust_, You didn't steal anything. You explained the problem and solution thoroughly.